# Inner join SQL syntax in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, join

This is my select SQL syntax to display the category choices,
but what I need to do is display the corresponding category chosen based on equipment_id

I got 2 tables, tblOfficeEquipmentCategory and tblOfficeEquipmentProfile

I need to inner join tblOfficeEquipmentProfile so I can add the WHERE equipment_id = '"txtid.text"'

What would be the corresponding SQL syntax

```vb
Public Sub DisplayCategory()
    'based on oe_id
    Dim sqlconn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
    sqlconn.ConnectionString = "server = SKPI-APPS1;" & _
    "Database = EOEMS;integrated security=true"

    Dim sqlcommand As SqlCommand

    sqlconn.Open()
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("select * from tblOfficeEquipmentCategory", sqlconn)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    da.Fill(dt)
    cmbCategory.DataSource = dt
    cmbCategory.ValueMember = "CAT_Name"
    cmbCategory.DisplayMember = "CAT_ID"
    sqlconn.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `equipment_id` is located on table `tblOfficeEquipmentProfile` and a column `CAT_ID` which links it to table `tblOfficeEquipmentCategory`.

```
SELECT  a.CAT_Name
FROM    tblOfficeEquipmentCategory a
        INNER JOIN tblOfficeEquipmentProfile b
            ON a.CAT_ID = b.CAT_ID
WHERE   b.equipment_id = @ID
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: i will try sir, im really not used in to using parameters, but thanks for the info

Comment: i have seen in your previous question that you ask about parameters `:D` please do use it.

Comment: still configuring out on how to make it work sir im still debugging the code and parameters

Answer (score 0):

Best to start thinking about how to separate your data access from your presentation code. You need something like this:

```vb
Public Function DisplayCategory() 
    cmbCategory.ValueMember = "CAT_Name"
    cmbCategory.DisplayMember = "CAT_ID"
    cmbCategory.DataSource = GetEquipmentCategories(Convert.ToInt32(txtid.text))
End Sub

Public Function GetEquipmentCategories(ByVal EquipmentID As Integer) As DataTable
    'based on oe_id

    Dim sql As String = "SELECT a.CAT_ID, a.CAT_Name" & _ 
                       " FROM tblOfficeEquipmentCategory a" & _
                       " INNER JOIN tblOfficeEquipmentProfile b ON a.CAT_ID = b.CAT_ID" & _
                       " WHERE b.equipment_id = @ID"

    Dim result As New DataTable
    Using cn New SqlConnection("server=SKPI-APPS1;Database=EOEMS;integrated security=true"), _
          cmd As new SqlCommand(sql, cn)

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = EquipmentID

        cn.Open()
        Using rdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            result.Load(rdr)
        End Using
    End Using
    Return result
End Function
```

Comment: sir ID contains char and integer ex. oeq-su-001 what would be the corresponding sqldbtype

Comment: Match the sqldbtype to the column definition in sql server. Look here for the list of possibilities: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
        Dim sql = "Select  Authors.Au_ID, Authors.Author, [Title Author].ISBN FROM(Authors INNER JOIN [Title Author] ON Authors.Au_ID = [Title Author].Au_ID)"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   Try
        con.Open()
        Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim sql = "Select  Authors.Au_ID, Authors.Author, [Title Author].ISBN FROM(Authors INNER JOIN [Title Author] ON Authors.Au_ID = [Title Author].Au_ID)"
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = sql
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(dt)
        DGV2.DataSource = dt
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```