# How to inner join two datatables in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Does anyone have an example of how to do an inner join on two datatables in vb.net? I have tried several examples that I found but I haven't gotten one to work thus far.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It will be easier for someone to correct what you've tried than come up with something from scratch which may still not work.

Comment: sure i have two datatables populated; the first dt1 and the second dt2 and this is the line where I'm trying to store my results:      Dim result() As DataRow = (as of right now I don't have anything here) I'm needing the structure to do a basic join. I think I could figure the rest out once I get just a basic structure

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027369/inner-join-sql-syntax-in-vb-net                                                                All your going to get with explanations like that are links to people that have already asked the same question you are asking. We need actual code samples, error messages, locations of error.

Comment: What database are you working with? The syntax is different for different databases.

Answer (score 5):

Your question is pretty vague, but maybe this helps anyway:

```
Dim both = From row1 In dataTable1.AsEnumerable()
           Join row2 In dataTable2.AsEnumerable()
           On row1.Field(Of String)("ColumnName") Equals row2.Field(Of String)("ColumnName")

For Each r1r2 In both
    Dim row1 = String.Format("{0}", String.Join(",", r1r2.row1.ItemArray))
    Dim row2 = String.Format("{0}", String.Join(",", r1r2.row2.ItemArray))
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} | {1}", row1, row2))
Next
```